# How to check Azure function is running on local environment? `RoleEnvironment` is not working in Azure Functions

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azure-cloud-services

I have a condition in code where i need to check if current environment is not local.i have used  `!RoleEnvironment.IsEmulated`, now this is not working in Azure functions but works in Cloud service. Same code is Shared in Cloud service also, so solution should work with cloud service and azure functions.

how can i check current environment is local not hosted/deployed?

Comment: RoleEnvironment is only available for Cloud Services. One thing you could try to do is add a reference for `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime` in your functions project.

Comment: @GauravMantri: this is not working it throws error : `the role environment has not been initialized`

Comment: That's what I feared. I think only way you could do it would be to refactor the code and pass this as a parameter to your method. From the function code, you will pass false. From cloud services code, you will pass the actual value of RoleEnvironment member value.

Comment: but what about other properties, like `RoleEnvironment.CurrentRoleInstance.Id, RoleEnvironment.IsActive` etc. i need an alternative `RoleEnvironment` or way to initialize `RoleEnvironment ` in azure functions.

Comment: do you find any solution?

Answer (score 20):

Based on answer by Fabio Cavalcante, here is a working Azure function that checks the current running environment (local or hosted):

```
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host;
using System;

namespace AzureFunctionTests
{
    public static class WhereAmIRunning
    {
        [FunctionName("whereamirunning")]
        public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post", Route = null)]HttpRequestMessage req, TraceWriter log)
        {
            bool isLocal = string.IsNullOrEmpty(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("WEBSITE_INSTANCE_ID"));

            string response = isLocal ? "Function is running on local environment." : "Function is running on Azure.";

            return req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, response);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: do you find any solution?

Comment: I think it's a bit risky to depend on some internal implementation. I have found there is relatively simple way of achieving it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66209057/1671558

Answer (score 19):

You can use the [`AZURE_FUNCTIONS_ENVIRONMENT` environment variable](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/4491), which is set automatically in local development:

```
Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AZURE_FUNCTIONS_ENVIRONMENT"); // set to "Development" locally
```

Note that when deployed/published (i.e. Azure), you'd need to set the environment variable yourself (e.g. function app settings in Azure).

Comment: This solution works well for me in Python (`os.getenv("AZURE_FUNCTIONS_ENVIRONMENT") == 'Development'` means local) -- while WEBSITE_INSTANCE_ID does not appear to be set when running Python

Comment: when running locally  it says `Development` but while published  it says nothing at all. what am i doing wrong?

Comment: I have experienced that `AZURE_FUNCTIONS_ENVIRONMENT` cannot be relied upon. There are multiple errors in Azure that can set it to Development e.g. when docs clearly says it should be Production. I have found there is relatively simple way of achieving it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66209057/1671558

Comment: @IlyaChernomordik as mentioned in the answer, it's not automatically set in Azure - it needs to be set explicitly.

Comment: Even that does not always work unfortunately due to some bugs. So you can set the variable explicitly and it will generally work, but there are scenarios when it stops working. Like disabling/enabling, redeploying. They are clearly bugs, but they exist nonetheless... E.g. here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/6239

Answer (score 19):

I am not sure it is a good idea to be dependent on some internal implementation like e.g. `WEBSITE_INSTANCE_ID` advised in the other answers.

I have just used a very simple approach by defining my own environment variable via `local.settings.json`:

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet",
    "IS_RUNNING_LOCALLY": true
  }
}
```

then I just check like that:

```
bool isLocal = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("IS_RUNNING_LOCALLY") == "true";
```

It is a workaround, but it's easy and intuitive and should be rather safe.

I tried with `AZURE_FUNCTIONS_ENVIRONMENT`, but one cannot set it in the local file as the runtime complains that it already exists, which seems like very stupid as one could have just set environment to "Local" e.g.

P.S. It seems that relying on e.g. default Environment is risky since there are multiple bugs related to it and you are not quite guaranteed for it to be "Production" as the documentation claims. See e.g. [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/blob/efb55da/src/WebJobs.Script/Config/ScriptSettingsManager.cs#L25).

Comment: Yup, `AZURE_FUNCTIONS_ENVIRONMENT` has issues: https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/6239

Comment: Another workaround approach is preprocessor directives

Comment: Per my understanding the documentation does make it clear that the value for `AZURE_FUNCTIONS_ENVIRONMENT` is "Development" when running locally with core tools. Otherwise the value can be "Staging" or "Producion". Apparently there are issues in that you cannot override this value and that Microsoft allows only these three environments, but for to original question on finding out whether running locally or in the cloud, this seems to be the solution. If you need more control, then using a custom var is probably needed.

Comment: The problem is that while your understanding is probably correct, the reality of Azure Functions is often such that it is not the same as documentation. I.e. it is either a bug in the functions runtime or documentation, which leads to me not trusting this exact part anyway. I do not know what leads to it, but sometimes it just happens

Comment: I see. And I just tested that on local env the variable is "Developmet", but at least on one of my Azure envs it undefined. Basically this functionality suits me well, but I'll have to consider whether this is reliable or not as stated by you and others.

Answer (score 5):

You can use an approach similar to what the actual runtime uses to identify whether it is running on Azure:
https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-script/blob/efb55da/src/WebJobs.Script/Config/ScriptSettingsManager.cs#L25

In this case, the runtime checks for the presence of an app setting named `WEBSITE_INSTANCE_ID`

Comment: To give a bit more detail: !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("WEBSITE_INSTANCE_ID"))

Comment: Does not work when debugging using Azure Function Tools locally.

Comment: do you find any solution?

Comment: AntoineC's answer is apparently the best solution possible. Check if this `WEBSITE_INSTANCE_ID` is empty, if it is, you are in **dev environment**... Now, it's only me or sometimes Microsoft lacks of standards with Azure Functions? I mean, why there isn't a simple way to do a simple thing like this?