# Check what environment Azure Functions is running on

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I need to check what environment, local or Azure, Azure Functions is running on.

Below is the code based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45026215/how-to-check-azure-function-is-running-on-local-environment-roleenvironment-i) and [this](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/blob/efb55da/src/WebJobs.Script/Config/ScriptSettingsManager.cs#L25)

```
var isLocal = string.IsNullOrEmpty(GetEnvironmentVariable("WEBSITE_INSTANCE_ID")
```

Is this a documented feature, or stable feature?

If not, is there an alternative?

Azure function 2.x

VS 2017

Comment: Wouldn't the simplest thing be to set your own env variable?

Comment: Setting own env variable works, but if built-in feature supports it, it is better.

Comment: better how? Setting your own means you can guarantee no breaking changes

Comment: avoid reinventing the wheel

Comment: It's hardly re-inventing the wheel.... In fact, you aren't reinventing anything because there isn't (as far as I am aware) any environment variables set by Azure to explicitly indicate you are running in a host environment.

Comment: `WEBSITE_INSTANCE_ID` looks a fairly reliable option, however, the point still stands, it's not a guarantee.

Comment: It is practical reliable to use it to indicate that you are running in Azure env (not local).   In fact, Kudu (Scm site) uses exactly that. See  https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/blob/f2f8e4c201682cd172c919c7c4e0c75dbca47833/Kudu.Core/Environment.cs#L369-L372

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Azure App Service sets some environment variables with information about your Web App/Function App running on Azure.

- **WEBSITE_SITE_NAME** - The name of the site.
- **WEBSITE_SKU** - The sku of the site (Possible values: Free, Shared, Basic, Standard).
- **WEBSITE_COMPUTE_MODE** - Specifies whether website is on a dedicated or shared VM/s (Possible values: Shared, Dedicated).
- **WEBSITE_HOSTNAME** - The Azure Website's primary host name for the site (For example: site.azurewebsites.net). Note that custom hostnames are not accounted for here.
- **WEBSITE_INSTANCE_ID** - The id representing the VM that the site is running on (If site runs on multiple instances, each instance will have a different id).
- **WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION** - The default node version this website is using.
- **WEBSOCKET_CONCURRENT_REQUEST_LIMIT** - The limit for websocket's concurrent requests.

You can use `WEBSITE_INSTANCE_ID` to get the id of instance hosting your Function App

```
public static class TestFunction
    {
        [FunctionName("TestFunction")]
        public static void Run([TimerTrigger("0 */5 * * * *")]TimerInfo myTimer, ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("WEBSITE_INSTANCE_ID"));
        }
    }
```

Reference: https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-runtime-environment#environment